# ¿Qué es el StackOverFlowError en java?

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código:

```
  public class Recursividad1 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            System.out.println("El factorial es: "+NumeroEntero.getFactorial(5));
            System.out.println("El factorial es: "+NumeroEntero.getPotencia(5, 2));
        }
        
    }
```

y esta es la clase donde están los métodos recursivos:

```
public class NumeroEntero {
    private static int devuelveFactorial(int numero) {
        if (numero == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return numero * devuelveFactorial(numero--);
        }
    }
    private static int devuelvePotencia(int valor, int potencia) {
        if (potencia == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return valor * devuelvePotencia(valor,potencia--);
        }
    }
    public static int getPotencia(int valor2, int potencia2){
        return devuelvePotencia(valor2, potencia2);
    }
    public static int getFactorial(int numero2){
        return devuelveFactorial(numero2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### ¿Qué es el stack?

El stack en java es una pila en la que se almacenan los datos referentes a la ejecución de los métodos (variables internas, y demás).

### ¿Qué es el StackOverflow?

Cada vez que haces una llamada a un método, se reserva memoria en el stack. Teniendo en cuenta que la memoria es finita, siempre existe la posibilidad de que esa memoria se acabe llenando.

Cuando esa memoria se llena y haces una llamada más a otro método nuevo, la JRE no es capaz de guardar los datos necesarios en memoria porque está llena, y entonces es cuando se lanza el StackOverflow.

### ¿Por qué se da en llamadas recursivas?

Del punto anterior te habrás dado cuenta de que, en teoría, es bastante fácil forzar un StackOverflow. La parte buena es que en java, hay un montón de optimizaciones, tanto del recolector de basura como por parte del compilador para evitar cosas así.

Un punto en el que no se puede evitar, sin embargo, es en las llamadas recursivas:

> Cuando llamas a un método desde otro en java, se guarda la memoria del método inicial y el recolector de basura no puede limpiarlo.

Esto normalmente no es problema porque no suele haber una cola de llamadas muy larga entre métodos, pero en una llamada recursiva infinita, el stack se llena rápidamente.

Por eso es muy importante dejar un retorno que se acerque cada vez más al caso trivial, que en tu ejercicio es `numero == 0`.

### ¿Cuál es tu error?

Tu error se da en esta línea:

```
return numero * devuelveFactorial(numero--);
```

No es fácil de cazar a simple vista. El problema es que al hacer `numero--` estás aplicando un **post-decremento**. Es decir, java va a ejecutar primero el retorno, **y después de devolver el resultado, decrementar el valor de `numero`, pero ya es demasiado tarde**.

Arreglarlo es tan fácil como cambiar el post-decremento por un `numero - 1`:

```
return numero * devuelveFactorial(numero - 1);
```

Comment: Gracias hermano, problema resuelta.

Answer (score 0):

**El StackOverflowError en Java**

En Java, el "StackOverflowError" es una excepción que ocurre cuando la pila de llamadas (stack) del programa alcanza su capacidad máxima. Esta excepción se produce cuando se produce una recursión infinita o una llamada a métodos anidados excesivamente profundos, lo que resulta en que la pila de llamadas se llene y no tenga más espacio para almacenar nuevas llamadas.

Cada vez que se realiza una llamada a un método en Java, el sistema agrega una entrada en la pila de llamadas para realizar un seguimiento de dónde se debe regresar después de que el método haya terminado de ejecutarse. Sin embargo, si hay una recursión infinita, es decir, un método que se llama a sí mismo repetidamente sin detenerse, o si hay una secuencia de llamadas anidadas muy profunda, la pila se llena rápidamente y se produce el StackOverflowError.

Este error generalmente se debe a un error de programación, como una condición de terminación incorrecta en una función recursiva o un diseño inadecuado del algoritmo. Para solucionarlo, es necesario revisar el código y corregir la lógica que está causando la recursión infinita o las llamadas anidadas excesivas.

Es importante destacar que el StackOverflowError es una excepción de tiempo de ejecución (runtime exception), lo que significa que ocurre durante la ejecución del programa y no puede ser capturada mediante una declaración de "throws" en la firma del método o mediante un bloque try-catch.

Comment: Esta pregunta ya tiene una respuesta aceptada desde hace 5 años. Revisa la respuesta aceptada por favor, revisar [answer], saludos.